# dynamically create multiple ListBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a table in SQL Server which gives me a list of products (PRODUCT), and the products category (CAT).  Right now I am putting all the products in the same ListBox:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["ProductsTbl"].Rows)
{
    string str = string.Format("{0}", row["PRODUCT"]);
    ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(str));
}
```

But I need to create as many listboxes as there are categories, and distribute those products according to the category.  Categories might be added or removed so I need to create them dynamically.

So lets say the table has 5 products in category 1, 4 products in category 2 and 7 products in category 3, I would need 3 Listboxes created.  The first with 5 items, the second with 4 and the last one with 7 items.  Any ideas ?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

1. Order `ProductsTbl` DataSet by `categoryId`
2. Add a new listbox every time you encounter a new `categoryId`

Something like this:

```
var catId = ds.Tables["ProductsTbl"].Rows[0].categoryId;
var listBox = ListBox1;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["ProductsTbl"].Rows)
{
    if(catId != row.categoryId)
    {
        catId = row.categoryId;
        listBox = new ListBox();
        Panel1.Controls.Add(listBox);
    } 
    string str = string.Format("{0}", row["PRODUCT"]);
    listBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(str));
}
```

Comment: Looks good but would I be able to fire events on those dynamically created controls ? For instance, for each ListBox, I will have a "select all" and "unselect all" button.

Comment: Yes - for server events have a look at this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794. For client events you can use a jquery live function. It will respond to dynamically created elements. See this link http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You could even create a control which would enable you to tweak the appearance and then create a new instance of it, much like the code by Joshia.

http://knol.google.com/k/creating-custom-controls-with-c-net#

Above is an example of custom controls